# Is it possible to retrieve Azure environment connection strings from the Kudu REST API?

Tags: rest, azure, kudu

I am accessing the REST API for Kudu as documented at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API.

Using the `GET /api/settings` endpoint I am able to retrieve the application settings configured in the Azure portal, however it does not include the connection strings configured in the Azure portal.

I'm not seeing any other endpoints that would include this information - is there any way to retrieve the connection strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Kudu API to do this. However, the recommended approach to get both APp Settings and Connection Strings is to go through the Azure ARM API.

e.g. to get Connection Strings:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{sub}/resourceGroups/{rg}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{appname}/config/connectionstrings/list?api-version=2016-08-01
```